# easy way to generate & manage ssl certificate manager kubernetes?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I want to generate SSL certificate automatically on Kubernetes. My site is already up and running but it is on HTTP:// not on HTTPS:// so which is the best way to provide them and generate the SSL certificate automatically.

I am new to k8s and learning. If the first time I manually install it then also the next time if the pod gets recreated the certificate will be deleted.

So suggest me easy way to manage certificate manager on K8s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few of options I can think of:

1. You can try the [certificate manager](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager) with [Letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificates.
2. You can try an a Kubernetes [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) with an ingress controller like [nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) also with Letsencrypt and [this](https://github.com/boxboat/kube-ingress-lets-encrypt) described [here](https://boxboat.com/2018/07/02/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-tls-secrets-all-namespaces/).
3. You can try a [Traefik](https://medium.com/@carlosedp/multiple-traefik-ingresses-with-letsencrypt-https-certificates-on-kubernetes-b590550280cf) ingress controller also with [Letsencrypt](https://blog.osones.com/en/kubernetes-ingress-controller-with-traefik-and-lets-encrypt.html).

Comment: thankyou for answer let me try one of them ..thankyou